# Combing Array Inline - LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am initialising and array from items in a list as follows:

```
MyArray[] Arrayitems = SomeOtherList
.Select(x => new MyArray[]
{
   ArrayPar1 = x.ListPar1,
}).ToArray()
```

I have a secondary List that i would like to add to the same array inline in the initialiser, something like this ():

```
    MyArray[] Arrayitems = SomeOtherList
    .Select(x => new MyArray[]
    {
       ArrayPar1 = x.ListPar1,
    }).ToArray()
   .Join(
    MyArray[] Arrayitems = SomeOtherListNo2
    .Select(x => new MyArray[]
    {
       ArrayPar1 = x.ListPar1,
    }).ToArray()
   );
```

Is this possible or will i have to combine everything before the initial select statement?

Comment: Do you mean `new MyArray()`? `new MyArray[]` does not make sense with your given initializer and result type.

Comment: Thanks Sefe, you're right but it's just an psuedo example, the actual code would have just 'Arrayitems' that is initialised elsewhere. You other answer is exactly what i need, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
MyArray[] Arrayitems = SomeOtherList.Concat(SomeOtherListNo2)
.Select(x => new MyArray()
{
   ArrayPar1 = x.ListPar1,
}).ToArray();
```

If items could be contained in both lists and you want them only once in your result, you can use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

```
MyArray[] Arrayitems = SomeOtherList.Union(SomeOtherListNo2)
.Select(x => new MyArray()
{
   ArrayPar1 = x.ListPar1,
}).ToArray();
```